# authenticating against AD using C#

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I have this code and am using VS 2005 - works nicely - however, if I try it using VS 2008, doesn't work. Any ideas?

webconfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add 
        name="ADService" 
        connectionString="LDAP://kingletvm.creighton.edu/DC=blue,DC=jays,DC=creighton,DC=edu" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <add 
            name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
                    System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                    PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
            connectionStringName="ADService" 
            attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" 
            description="Default AD connection"/>
        </providers>     
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

---

C# code:

```
Membership.ValidateUser(netid.Text, passwd.Text);
```

where `netid` and `passwd` come from text input boxes.

Comment: Do you get an exception thrown? If so, can you paste onto the end of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running in 3.5 (or 3.0) in VS 2008? What happens if you change the .NET Framework version to 2.0?
Are you getting any errors or is it just failing authentication?